# OWL API - which version to use (5 or 4)

Tags: owl, owl-api

I have some difficulties to find my way with the different versions of OWL API.
It seems there are to places from where you can get OWL-API:

http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/

and

https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi

From source forge you can get compiled versions (.jar files) of OWL API (the latest one is 4.1.4)

From github there are different branches:
version 5, the latest one seems to be 5.0.1
version 4, the latest one seems to be 4.2.3

on github there are also some code examples but only for version 3 and 4 but nothing for version 5.

What version should I use ?

Are there some code examples for version 5 ?

What is the official web site for OWL API ? Sourceforge or Github ?

Comment: GitHub. SourceForge is kept because of the mailing list only. The code examples for version 4 work with version 5 - there's a migration guide to version 5 in the GitHub wiki.

Comment: I've updated http://owlcs.github.io/owlapi/ with new release links

Answer (score 1):

### Edit

Ignazio posted [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36552726/owl-api-which-version-to-use-5-or-4#comment60729772_36553602) that is more authoritative than my original answer, and it sounds like you can use 4 or 5, and that rather than downloading directly, you should get jars from Maven Central.  The comment reads:

> *The site needs updating. Version 5 is stable. Version 4 is used a lot more - Protégé for example. Both are supported. The recommended way to get the binaries is Maven central.*

### Old Version

It sounds like you've already found the new and old sites, and I think all the answers can be found there.  But just in case, here's what I found while browsing the sites that you already linked to.

The [sourceforge site](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/) is still the first that comes up in Google for me, but it's not the latest site anymore.  In fact, it includes a link to the new site on GitHub:

> For the latest updates, code and documentation, please visit the new GitHub [web site](http://owlcs.github.io/owlapi/).

The GitHub site still links to the sourceforge download site for releases, and those go up through the 4.x series.  So it sounds like GitHub is the place for the source, but sourceforge is still used to deliver released jars.

About the versions, the GitHub site says (emphasis added):

> #### Exciting excerpt about future directions:
>
> *Version 5.0.0 is the next version of the OWL API, currently very much
>   in flux in terms of features and design.* If you fancy getting
>   involved, or have dreams for great new features, or even if you are
>   irked by some parts of the current design and wish to have your pain
>   eased, you are welcome to propose them: fill in an issue or email the
>   list with your proposal. Or, implement the change you would like to
>   see in the API and issue a pull request.

If you want a stable release, it sounds like you should stick with the 4.x releases for now.

Comment: The site needs updating. Version 5 is stable. Version 4 is used a lot more - Protégé for example. Both are supported. The recommended way to get the binaries is Maven central.

Comment: Hi Ignazio! Are there any reasoners for OWLAPI5? And, what about the performance of OWLAPI5? Thank you.